# Output html source tags inside shortcode

Tags: shortcode, tinymce

I have made a custom popup tiny mce button to add source code.This put shortcode like this

```
[source]
<h1>Hi</h1>
[/source]
```

To capture output I used

```
function caption_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
$content = do_shortcode($content);
return '<span itemprop="articleSection">'.wpautop($content).'</span>';
}
add_shortcode( 'source', 'caption_shortcode' );
```

This doesn't show `<h1>Hi</h1>` rather it convert h1 html tag.How can I make this show like `<h1>Hi</h1>`?

Comment: You know that [`wpautop()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wpautop/) is used to replace line breaks with paragraphs? And that would make the HTML perfectly invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
function caption_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
    $content = do_shortcode($content);
    return '<span itemprop="articleSection">'. str_replace( array( '<', '>' ), array( '&lt;', '&gt;' ), $content ) .'</span>';
}
add_shortcode( 'source', 'caption_shortcode' );

remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```